# How can I fix DEP0700 splashScreen in .NET MAUI

Tags: c#, maui

```
DEP0700: Registration of the app failed. [0x80073CF6] AppxManifest.xml(33,27): error 0x80070003: Cannot install or update package C2825F9A-1C95-43C1-96C9-3ABE72D02D1D_9zz4h110yvjzm because the splash screen image [splashSplashScreen.png] cannot be located. Verify that the package contains an image that can be used as a splash screen for the application, and that the package manifest points to the correct location in the package where this splash screen image can be found.
```

How can I fix this error in .NET MAUI ? This error say that splashSplashScreen.png is missing. It sometimes happens after the deletion of my bin directory or obj directory.

Currently I delete my bin and obj folders several times in a row and regenerate the project several times also so that it works again. I would like to avoid this problem and know where it comes from.

Comment: This only happens when I deploy the projet on Windows

Comment: Try to run visual studio as an administrator

Comment: Do not post errors as images. On top of everything, it is in another language, and I cannot even write it, even if I wanted to.

Comment: Did you try https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1178661/how-to-fix-error-dep0700-maui-net7-0 ?

Comment: @Poulpynator yes I tried

Comment: MAUI will convert the SVG file indside `/Ressources/Splash/splash.svg` to a PNG file which will be embeded in the app. You can setup this file inside the project file with `<MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\Splash\splash.svg" Color="#512BD4" BaseSize="128,128" />`, I had some bad experiences with changing this file name so maybe that's coming from there (try to delete it if you are not using it for now). Also if you are working with Android try to uninstall all your app packages (there may be several) on your device.

Comment: @QuentinGuillaume It's because MAUI became preview 13 after being updated, but not updating the template to preview 13. You said you tried per this [How to fix Error DEP0700 Maui .NET7.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1178661/how-to-fix-error-dep0700-maui-net7-0), did the error reoccur after following that guide?

Comment: @Alexandar May  I just had it happen updating MAUI to .NET 8

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of being laughed at, I've spent too much time researching and trying to resolve this and **a simple computer restart did the trick** eventually. I had deleted my `bin` and `obj` folders, was required to run a dotnet restore command on the Maui project, and then faced this DEP0700 issue for hours:

1. Restart PC
2. Clean and Rebuild solution

I suspect either a temporary artifact caused this issue. The restart caused it to be rebuilt correctly.

Comment: I have never tried to build MAUI projects on windows, BUT I have never restarted my Mac for the same 